Ubuntu 24.04 pauses during startup with a small "Ubuntu 24.04" + changing dots
During Ubuntu boot up it has started pausing about a minute displaying nothing but "Ubuntu 24.04" above four colored (and changing) dots. This is near the upper left-hand corner of the screen. Then it continues normally with the log on screen. I cannot identify any change that caused this.
Here is the requested output from systemd-analyze blame. Sorry about the lack of \n.
1min 984ms NetworkManager.service
1min 774ms snapd.seeded.service
1min 657ms snapd.service
1min 644ms gpu-manager.service
   12.396s apt-daily-upgrade.service
    8.429s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
    3.144s plymouth-quit-wait.service
    1.066s fwupd.service
     464ms postfix@-.service
     222ms dev-nvme0n1p2.device
     177ms apport.service
     149ms user@1000.service
     142ms cups.service
     133ms dev-loop7.device
     127ms dev-loop2.device
     125ms dev-loop1.device
     124ms networkd-dispatcher.service
     122ms dev-loop5.device
     116ms dev-loop6.device
     114ms dev-loop4.device
     112ms udisks2.service
     102ms gnome-remote-desktop.service
      96ms com.system76.PowerDaemon.service
      95ms dev-loop3.device
      89ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
      83ms dev-loop10.device
      83ms dev-loop0.device
      81ms upower.service
      78ms rsyslog.service
      75ms dev-loop27.device
      74ms dev-loop29.device
      73ms systemd-journal-flush.service
      73ms polkit.service
      72ms dev-loop28.device
      70ms dev-loop30.device
      69ms dev-loop31.device
      69ms dev-loop26.device
      68ms dev-loop24.device
      68ms accounts-daemon.service
      68ms dev-loop23.device
      67ms dev-loop32.device
      67ms dev-loop20.device
      67ms dev-loop25.device
      66ms dev-loop22.device
      65ms dev-loop21.device
      65ms dev-loop33.device
      65ms dev-loop19.device
      64ms dev-loop17.device
      64ms dev-loop18.device
      63ms dev-loop15.device
      63ms dev-loop16.device
      62ms dev-loop9.device
      62ms systemd-resolved.service
      61ms dev-loop12.device
      60ms dev-loop13.device
      59ms dev-loop14.device
      59ms dev-loop11.device
      59ms dev-loop8.device
      58ms update-notifier-download.service
      58ms systemd-journald.service
      53ms systemd-udevd.service
      52ms lm-sensors.service
      51ms systemd-logind.service
      50ms ModemManager.service
      47ms gdm.service
      45ms avahi-daemon.service
      44ms bluetooth.service
      43ms fwupd-refresh.service
      42ms systemd-timesyncd.service
      42ms snapd.apparmor.service
      42ms apparmor.service
      42ms systemd-random-seed.service
      41ms systemd-oomd.service
      39ms dbus.service
      38ms systemd-sysctl.service
      36ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
      36ms snap-bare-5.mount
      35ms grub-common.service
      35ms snap-chromium-2873.mount
      35ms snap-chromium-2890.mount
      34ms snap-core18-2823.mount
      34ms snap-core18-2829.mount
      33ms snap-core20-2264.mount
      32ms snap-core20-2318.mount
      32ms snap-core22-1122.mount
      31ms wpa_supplicant.service
      31ms snap-core22-1380.mount
      30ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
      30ms plymouth-start.service
      30ms snap-cups-1047.mount
      29ms snap-cups-1052.mount
      29ms snap-firefox-4424.mount
      28ms switcheroo-control.service
      28ms snap-firefox-4451.mount
      27ms snap-firmware\x2dupdater-121.mount
      26ms keyboard-setup.service
      26ms snap-firmware\x2dupdater-127.mount
      26ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3855\x2dA8D4.service
      26ms snap-freecad-759.mount
      25ms thermald.service
      25ms snap-freecad-908.mount
      24ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-198.mount
      24ms pulseaudio-enable-autospawn.service
      24ms colord.service
      23ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-143.mount
      23ms alsa-restore.service
      23ms snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-172.mount
      22ms snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-176.mount
      21ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount
      21ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
      21ms snap-kde\x2dframeworks\x2d5\x2d99\x2dqt\x2d5\x2d15\x2d7\x2dcore20-7.mount
      20ms snap-shotcut-1389.mount
      20ms snap-shotcut-1447.mount
      20ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
      20ms snapd.socket
      19ms snap-snap\x2dstore-1134.mount
      19ms systemd-modules-load.service
      18ms snap-snap\x2dstore-1147.mount
      18ms e2scrub_reap.service
      18ms systemd-backlight@leds:system76_acpi::kbd_backlight.service
      17ms snap-snapd-21465.mount
      17ms kerneloops.service
      17ms snap-snapd-21759.mount
      16ms snap-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration-157.mount
      16ms snap-snapd\x2ddesktop\x2dintegration-83.mount
      15ms snap-thunderbird-480.mount
      14ms systemd-remount-fs.service
      14ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
      14ms snap-thunderbird-482.mount
      14ms snap-yubioath\x2ddesktop-13.mount
      12ms plymouth-read-write.service
      12ms var-snap-firefox-common-host\x2dhunspell.mount
      11ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-5a2e642d\x2d3593\x2d4a24\x2da2fd\x2def8dd9870bc1.swap
      10ms systemd-binfmt.service
      10ms dev-hugepages.mount
      10ms dev-mqueue.mount
       9ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       9ms atd.service
       9ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
       9ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev-early.service
       8ms nvidia-persistenced.service
       8ms rtkit-daemon.service
       8ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       8ms modprobe@configfs.service
       7ms systemd-user-sessions.service
       7ms modprobe@drm.service
       6ms modprobe@fuse.service
       6ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
       6ms boot-efi.mount
       6ms openvpn.service
       5ms systemd-rfkill.service
       5ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       5ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       4ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
       3ms console-setup.service
       3ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
       3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
       3ms ufw.service
       3ms sys-kernel-config.mount
       2ms modprobe@loop.service
       2ms modprobe@dm_mod.service
       1ms setvtrgb.service
     909us postfix.service


Please [edit] your question by adding the output of systemd-analyze blame.
